# Difference between the results of two independent queries neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 subqueries that returns 2 sets of users (each query return one set of users)

First query :

```
MATCH (:User {user_id: "69b3315a-ba4a-4021-94e1-0f494f9b957f"})-->(first_set_of_users)
RETURN first_set_of_users
```

Second query :

```
MATCH (:User {user_id: "69b3315a-ba4a-4021-94e1-0f494f9b957f"})<-[:LIKES]-(likers)-[:LIKES]->(v)
WITH DISTINCT v
MATCH (second_set_of_users)-[:LIKES]->(v)
RETURN second_set_of_users, COUNT(*) AS recoWeight
ORDER BY recoWeight DESC
```

What I want to finally return is all users from `second_set_of_users` minus the one in `first_set_of_users` and `ORDER BY recoWeight DESC`

How can I do that in just one query ? Everything I tried led to cartesian products of queries and took forever while each independent query takes less than a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MATCH (:User {user_id: "69b3315a-ba4a-4021-94e1-0f494f9b957f"})-->(first_set_of_users)
WITH collect(first_set_of_users) AS list_of_first_set_of_users
MATCH (:User {user_id: "69b3315a-ba4a-4021-94e1-0f494f9b957f"})<-[:LIKES]-(likers)-[:LIKES]->(v)
WITH DISTINCT v, list_of_first_set_of_users
MATCH (second_set_of_users)-[:LIKES]->(v)
WITH second_set_of_users, COUNT(*) AS recoWeight
WHERE NOT second_set_of_users IN list_of_first_set_of_users
RETURN second_set_of_users, recoWeight
ORDER BY recoWeight DESC
```

Explanation.
Using `WITH` clause we could pass the result of the first query into the second query.
And then using `WHERE NOT IN` we could filter the result of the second query.